# Log Correlation ID with Vertx

Tags: java, logging, vert.x

I'd like to add a correlation ID to my logs, so that I can follow calls across different servers. However I am using Vert.x and can not use MDC or ThreadLocal. Any Ideas?

Comment: Some discussion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vertx/9rHzX3vVg8Y

Comment: duplicate question please see the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45045621/how-to-correlate-log-events-in-distributed-vertx-system